# how to expand an excel table automatically to fill the size of a dynamic array

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am making a leave request for witch will record the leaves for some employees. I made a dashboard to show the inserted leaves in an easy and summarized way as the following.

[image]

What I want is to expand the table automatically to fit the size of the dynamic array function automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
Dim mySheetName As Worksheet
Dim myTableName As String
Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myEnd As Integer
myTableName = "Table1"
Set mySheetName = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set myTable = mySheetName.ListObjects(myTableName)

myEnd = mySheetName.Range("A" & mySheetName.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

'Resize the table:
myTable.Resize Range("C9:AK" & myEnd)
```

Comment: Thank you Toni, I think this code snippet will work only if the dynamic array size is more than the table size. I want to find a method that get the length of the spilled array and change the size of the table accordingly.